# Storing multiple values using Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i want to know how to insert the multiple array values by parent,child and subchild.I am having an array values as:

```
Array
(
 [Gift] => Array
    (
        [SILVER] => Array
            (
                [0] => SILVER GLASS
                [1] => SILVER COIN GIFT
            )
    )
 [Electronics] => Array
    (
        [watch] => Array
            (
                [0] => Fasttrack
                [1] => Titan
            )
    )
 )
```

The Gift Array is the parent category, SILVER array is the subcategory for Gift and the third children array which is children for the SILVER. How to insert the values by parent, child and subchildren dynamically? Can you please help me how the array values insert using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: show your database table structure

Comment: I am having an field like id,cat_name ,cat_parent,createdtime

Comment: In the table the cat_parent is 0 for the first parent category.The second level category for cat_parent value is which is depend on the parent category id.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be: $gift['SILVER'][0] ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use recursion, ex.

```
    |  id  |     name      |  parent  |
    |   1  |  Electronics  |    0     |
    |   2  |     Watch     |    1     |
```

In parent column you need to save parent id, in example, there is row with name 'Electronics', and another with name 'Watch', first row have parent id '0' so it means that row is category, but another row have parent id 1, so that row is the child of Electronics.

Comment: can you explain how the array values split and insert values like first level category,second level category and third level category?

Comment: How the array values insert into database through loop?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it having a table structure id_cat,cat_name,cat_parent

Code is:

```
$arraytest=//given array;
repeateIt($arraytest,0);
function repeateIt($arr,$i) {
global $link;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
        $id=  mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO category values (NULL,'{$key}',{$i})");
        repeateIt($value,$i+1);
    }else{
        $id=  mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO category values (NULL,'{$value}',{$i})");
    }
}
```

}